# How to capture session level details in a table

Tags: informatica

I have a requirement to capture session level details like session start time, end time, src success row, failedrows etc.. in a audit table. As all those details are available in prebuilt session variables i need to store these in a table. As of now what i am doing is, taking an assignment task in a workflow and assigning all these prebuilt session variables values for a particular session to wrkflow variables and passing these workflow variables to mapping variables using another non reusable session (the mapping which loads the table)  using pre variable assignment option.It is working fine for workflow which is having one session. But if i have to implement this for a workflow having more no of sessions this process will be tedious as i have to create assignment task for each of these sessions and need to create non resuable session which calls a mapping to load into audit table.

```
 So i am wondering is there any alternative solution to get this job done? I am thinking of a solution in which if we can able to captures audit details of all session in a file and pass this file as a input to a mapping to load this data at once into table. Is this possible? any solution?
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [ETL Operational framework](http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2014/01/an-etl-framework-for-operational.html)

It covers and end-to-end solution that should fit your needs and be quite easy to extend if you have multiple sessions - all you'd need to do is apply similar `Post session commands` before running the final session that loads the stats to database.